# Windows 7 Gadgets - safety?

Tags: windows-7

I know that Microsoft has discontinued Gadgets.  However it seems that it is really the sidebar that can have a dangerous gadget installed in it.  So, my question is:  I use the following gadgets as originally distributed by MS - are those safe or should I totally disable all gadgets?  I have no other 3rd party gadgets nor do I want any.  I use Clock. CPU Usage, local temperature, and calendar.

Comment: I think it's kind of up to you.  They can cause a serious security risk, at least according to Microsoft, but I've had them on a couple computers for years and have never had an issue, probably a case of "use at your own risk".

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has stopped supporting Gadgets as they are more prone towards the security risks. It may even provide a chance to the exploiters to take control of your system. Hence it is recommended to disable Gadgets so as to make sure your system is completely secure.  You can safely disable the Desktop Gadgets by following the below article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dn261332